# Mysql IF conditional Left Join same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "Tasks" table for work.
There are 2 types of users in the system "Admin" and "Agent" both are stored in different tables called "Admin" and "Agents".

```
**Table Admin**
admin_id           |  1
admin_name         |  John
admin_surname      |  Doe

**Table Agents**
agent_id           |  1
agents_name        |  Sally
agents_surname     |  Zoe
```

And there is "Tasks" table where users can add task/requests for other users.

```
**Table Tasks**
task_id            | 1
task_inquirer_type | (1 if Admin, 2 if Agent)
task_inquirer_id   | ID from related user table
task_assigned_type | (1 if Admin, 2 if Agent)
task_assigned_id   | ID from related user table
task_text          | text
```

I'm trying to get all records in one Mysql Query with joining Admin and Agent tables to get names and surnames of inquirers and assigned users.

With the below SQL i can get the records for one user.

```
    SELECT tasks.*,
    admins.admin_name as inquirer_name, admins.admin_surname as inquirer_surname

    FROM tasks

    INNER JOIN admins on admins.admin_id = tasks.task_inquirer_id
    WHERE tasks.task_inquirer_type = 1 
    AND task_assigned_id = 1 AND task_assigned_type = 1


    UNION


    SELECT tasks.*,
    agents.agent_name as inquirer_name, agents.agent_surname as inquirer_surname

    FROM tasks

    INNER JOIN agents on agents.agent_id = tasks.task_inquirer_id
    WHERE tasks.task_inquirer_type = 2 
    AND task_assigned_id = 1 AND task_assigned_type = 1
```

With this query, i can get all records assigned to Admin (1) user with ID (1). But i have made another page where i would like to list all records and get all names as "inquirer" and "assigned" in the list. I've tried the query below but somehow it gave me wrong names but the rest is ok.

```
SELECT tasks.*,
inquirer.admin_name as inquirername, inquirer.admin_surname as inquirersurname,
assigned.admin_name as assignedname, assigned.admin_surname as assignedsurname

FROM tasks

INNER JOIN admins AS inquirer on inquirer.admin_id = tasks.task_inquirer_id
INNER JOIN admins AS assigned on assigned.admin_id = tasks.task_assigned_id

WHERE tasks.task_inquirer_type = 1


UNION


SELECT tasks.*,
inquirer.agent_name as inquirername, inquirer.agent_surname as inquirersurname,
assigned.agent_name as assignedname, assigned.agent_surname as assignedsurname

FROM tasks

INNER JOIN agents AS inquirer on inquirer.agent_id = tasks.task_inquirer_id
INNER JOIN agents AS assigned on assigned.agent_id = tasks.task_assigned_id

WHERE tasks.task_inquirer_type = 2
```

Any help how should i process the query? I know that I've to look for both types, not only 1 type as "WHERE tasks.task_inquirer_type = 1 or 2". There should be "WHERE tasks.task_assigned_type = 1 or 2" too in the query which i can not figure out how to.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should change your data model. As is, you cannot guarantee data consistency. You could put any number into `task_inquirer_id` and `task_assigned_id`; the DBMS cannot help you controlling that an agent ID really exists in the agent table for instance.

If the tables `admin` and `agent` are very similar as in your example, make it one `person` table, with a flag showing whether the person is an agent or an admin. You'd change the `tasks` table as follows:

```
task_id (PK)
task_inquirer_person_id (FK not nullable)
task_assigned_person_id (FK not nullable)
```

with foreign keys to the `person` table. Whether an admin or agent will be implicit by the records linked.

If the tables `admin` and `agent` differ very much, then only change your `tasks` table like this:

```
task_id (PK)
task_inquirer_admin_id (FK nullable)
task_inquirer_agent_id (FK nullable)
task_assigned_admin_id (FK nullable)
task_assigned_agent_id (FK nullable)
```

Add foreign keys to the main tables as shown and add constraints to ensure that always only one inquirer and one assigned person is set in a record.

Querying the table will be much simpler then.

Comment: While I agree that it would be better to change the design it is not true that you cannot guarantee data consistency, e.g. you could use triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm already using a single user table version and another task table which worked pretty well in past few years but i had to separate admin, agent and user databases as they got extremely different in the time. So i have to keep them separated.

Comment: Okay. As you see I also have an advice on how to change the `tasks` table when the tables `admin` and `agent` differ very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it (the join everything and select conditionally approach, you could also work with sub-selects):

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  CASE WHEN b1.agent_id IS NULL THEN a1.admin_name ELSE b1.agent_name END inquirername,
  CASE WHEN b1.agent_id IS NULL THEN a1.admin_surname ELSE b1.agent_surname END inquirersurname,
  CASE WHEN b2.agent_id IS NULL THEN a2.admin_name ELSE b2.agent_name END assignedname,
  CASE WHEN b2.agent_id IS NULL THEN a2.admin_surname ELSE b2.agent_surname END assignedsurname
FROM
  tasks t LEFT JOIN
  admin a1 ON a1.admin_id = t.inquirer_id AND t.inquirer_type = 1 LEFT JOIN
  admin a2 ON a2.admin_id = t.assigned_id AND t.assigned_type = 1 LEFT JOIN
  agents b1 ON b1.agent_id = t.inquirer_id AND t.inquirer_type = 2 LEFT JOIN
  agents b2 ON b2.agent_id = t.assigned_id AND t.assigned_type = 2
;
```